# R Shiny Reactive SelectInput

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

Hello everybody,

I need your help please : I have a dataframe named data_test, you can reproduce it with these lines :

```
 PC<-c('001','002','003','004','005','006','007','008','009','010')
 A<-c('2','2','1','1','2','0','2','0','1','0')
 B<-c('0','2','0','0','1','0','0','0','1','0')
 C<-c('1','0','0','0','2','2','0','0','0','1')
 NB_CARS<-c('1','3','1','1','0','2','1','3','2','2')
 data_test <- data.frame(PC, A, B, C, NB_CARS)
```

And I have three linked chekboxGroupInputs named "variable1", "variable2" and "variable3". When I check some of these chekboxGroupInputs, the number of matching rows is updated. But I would like to insert a reactive SelectInput to show the resulting number of cars based on the "NB_CARS" variable, and I don't manage to do that. Could you please help me ? Thanks much.

This is my code :

```
 ui <- fluidPage(
   fluidRow(
     column(3,
            checkboxGroupInput("variable1", "Occurences of column A :",
                               c("Yes (1)" = "1",
                                 "No (2)" = "2",
                                 "Perhaps (0)" = "0")),
            checkboxGroupInput("variable2", "Occurences of column B :",
                               c("Yes (1)" = "1",
                                 "No (2)" = "2",
                                 "Perhaps (0)" = "0")),
            checkboxGroupInput("variable3", "Occurences of column C :",
                               c("Yes (1)" = "1",
                                 "No (2)" = "2",
                                 "Perhaps (0)" = "0"))),

     column(3,
            tableOutput("data")),

     column(3,
            textOutput("result"))
   )
 )

 server <- function(input, output, session) {

   result <- 0

   df1 <- reactive({
     filter(data_test,
            (is.null(input$variable1) | A %in% input$variable1),
            (is.null(input$variable2) | B %in% input$variable2),
            (is.null(input$variable3) | C %in% input$variable3))
   })

   output$result <- renderText(paste("Number of occurences = ", nrow(df1())))


   output$data <- renderTable({df1()})

 }

 shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this is what you have in mind, but maybe this will be helpful (if not, let me know).

You can add a `selectInput` in your `ui` that will be updated by `updateSelectInput` in your `server`.

**Edit 1**: The `output$result` is modified to show the number of rows that match `input$numcars`. In other words, if you select from the new `input$numcars` `selectInput`, you will see the number of times `NB_CARS` matches the selection made.

**Edit 2**: If you wish to add `All` as a choice, be aware that `NB_CARS` is a factor. So you were getting levels of the factor with unexpected results (such as a 4). You can use `as.character` before combining with `All` to get desired result.

Also, when you render the text, just check if the input is `All` - if it is, show number of rows. If not, show `NB_CARS` matches. See edited `server`.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(3,
           checkboxGroupInput("variable1", "Occurences of column A :",
                              c("Yes (1)" = "1",
                                "No (2)" = "2",
                                "Perhaps (0)" = "0")),
           checkboxGroupInput("variable2", "Occurences of column B :",
                              c("Yes (1)" = "1",
                                "No (2)" = "2",
                                "Perhaps (0)" = "0")),
           checkboxGroupInput("variable3", "Occurences of column C :",
                              c("Yes (1)" = "1",
                                "No (2)" = "2",
                                "Perhaps (0)" = "0")),
           selectInput("numcars", "Number of Cars", choices = NULL)),
    column(3,
           tableOutput("data")),

    column(3,
           textOutput("result"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  result <- 0

  df1 <- reactive({
    filter(data_test,
           (is.null(input$variable1) | A %in% input$variable1),
           (is.null(input$variable2) | B %in% input$variable2),
           (is.null(input$variable3) | C %in% input$variable3))
  })

  observe({
    updateSelectInput(session, "numcars", choices = c("All", unique(as.character(df1()[["NB_CARS"]]))))
  })

  output$result <- renderText({
    if (input$numcars == "All") {
      num_text <- nrow(df1())
    } else {
      num_text <- sum(df1()[["NB_CARS"]] == input$numcars)
    }
    paste("Number of occurences = ", num_text)
  })

  output$data <- renderTable({df1()})

}
```

Comment: Hello Ben, thank you very much for your help. I'm happy that the selectInput is reactive now, but is it possible to update the number of occurrences too ? For example, if I check "No" in the first checkboxgroupInput and if I check "Perhaps" in the third checkboxgroupInput, I can see that there are two rows in the table, and there are two choices in the selecInput : "1" and "3". If I choose "3", I would like the number of occurrences to be updated to "1" instead of "2" currently, at the right of the screen. I hope I'm clear. Thank you very much.

Comment: Hello Ben, sorry, my message is not comlete, thank you, it's nearly perfect : I just would like the textOutput to show the result of nrow of df1() if no choice is made in the selectInput. If a choice is made in selectInput, the result of sum(df1()[["NB_CARS"]] == input$numcars) is shown. So I would like to add the value "All" in the selecInput to take into account all values if there is no choice, but a "4" appears in the list and I don't know where it comes from. Further, is it possible to update the renderTable when we have made a choice in the selectinput ? Thank you very much for helping.

Comment: One more thing please : what kind of object is df1() ? I didn't succeeded in saving it into the workspace with "assign". Thank you

Comment: Thank you very much Ben, it's perfect. I asked how to save df1() as a data.frame in the workspace to learn how to save this kind of object because I tried with the command "assign(df1, df1(), envir = .GlobalEnv)" and it does not work. Later, I would like to proceed other treatments on this data.frame. Thank you again.

Comment: If you want the results of `df1()` to exist after the app is terminated, then you can do `df1_stored <<- df1()` maybe in your `observe`. If you want to access `df1()` elsewhere in your `server` function, you just call `df1()`. Alternatively, you can create `reactiveValues()` and define in `global.R` will make object available to all .R files in shiny app. Recommended reading is this on [scoping rules in shiny](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/scoping.html).

Comment: Ok Ben, I will read carefully the link you gave. Thank you very much for helping and all your explanations. Have a very nice day.